# Should I set block reference to nil AFTER execution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

After `[block copy]` and executed `block();`, should I set `block=nil`? Or does ARC already manage this for me so I don't have to do anything?
I'm a bit confused on how ARC manages block references here and I'm not sure setting the block to nil would break anything or not?

I have something like this. Any thoughts?

```
typedef void (^C3Block)(void);    // declare block, no return, no args

// set flag to get _previewImage, then call the block
- (void)takePreviewImageFromBufferWithBlock:(C3Block)block {
    _takePreviewImageBlock = [block copy]; // save block ref for calling later
    _shouldTakePreviewImageFromBuffer = YES;
}

- (void)gotPreviewImageFromBuffer {
    _takePreviewImageBlock(); // calls the block
    _takePreviewImageBlock = nil; // <---- should I do this???
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to set it to `nil`, and here is why:

Let's call the class these methods are in `ImageLoader`. Suppose I have a class `MyViewController` that has a strong reference to this `ImageLoader` (it's an instance variable, say), and passes it a block that retains `self` (i.e. the `MyViewController`). Why does it retain `self`? Well, your `ImageLoader` presumably works asynchronously, so, say, I want my `MyViewController` to be around long enough to handle the response.

Okay, so we have a retain cycle. The `MyViewController` retains the `ImageLoader`, which retains the block, which retains the `MyViewController`. However, if you simply `nil` the block variable at the end of the operation in `ImageLoader`, it will break this cycle. Otherwise these objects will never be deallocated. It kind of makes sense for `ImageLoader` to set the block variable to `nil` when its operation is done because it no longer "needs" it.

(You could also argue that the issue in the scenario above could be avoided by arranging the retains differently -- that `MyViewController` should *not* retain `ImageLoader`. Then, during the asynchronous operation, `ImageLoader` must still be retained by *something* from the ongoing operation. `ImageLoader` still retains the block which retains `MyViewController`. When the operation is done, the operation releasing `ImageLoader` will release everything, and everyone is happy, without needing to set the block variable to `nil`.)

Comment: so, do you mean setting the block variable `nil` at the end of operation will help **deallocating** the block and its retained `self` will also be deallocated?

Comment: @Hlung: well, when a heap block is deallocated, it releases the captured variables it retained

Answer (score 2):

Generally, there's no point in setting your block iVar to nil, since you most probably will reset it with the consecutive `-takePreviewImageFromBufferWithBlock:` call. From memory management point of view, `_takePreviewBlock` is an iVar and it's management by ARC will be the same as with any other iVar - it'll be properly released without your interaction when the owner class gets deallocated.

Answer (score 2):

If `_takePreviewImageBlock` is a property with **strong** attribute, then ARC will keep it as long as the object containing this property exists. 
As mentioned by @Eugene, it will reset after calling `takePreviewImageFromBufferWithBlock:`. 
After understanding this behavior, you should decide if it fits your design. If the owner will be deallocated right after, there's no need to nil its properties yourself. Otherwise, you should nil it if this block is no longer relevant to your logic and it will sit in memory for no good reason.